# Excel Maths function to PHP

Tags: php, excel, excel-formula, pow, exponentiation

I am having a problem converting an excel maths function to a php function, I have the majority of the code correct, however the last bit I cannot seem to get correct.

This is the excel function

```
=SUM((0.75*200000)*(1+(0.04/12))^(5*12))-(((0.04/12)*(0.75*200000)/((1-(1+(0.04/12))^(-(30*12)))))/(0.04/12))*((1+(0.04/12))^(5*12)-1)
```

This is my PHP code

```
((0.75*200000)*(pow(1+(0.04/12),(5*12)))) - (((0.04/12)*(0.75*200000) / (1-(pow(1+(0.04/12),-(30*12)))))/(0.04/12)) * (pow((1+(0.04/12)),(5*12)-1)) ;
```

At the moment my PHP code is getting the answer of -78,294.13 I need to get 135,671

I believe that the following code is wrong, but I cant seem to figure out why.

```
(pow((1+(0.04/12)),(5*12)-1))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have so many constants and brackets?

Comment: As I am aware, if you need to do "1+5-3" in EXCEL you can do "=1+5-3", so `SUM()` is not needed there, are you sure the Excel output is not wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have error in PHP calculation:

```
... * (pow((1+(0.04/12)),(5*12)-1)) ;
```

should be:

```
... * (pow((1+(0.04/12)),(5*12))-1) ;
```